# xml element gives no output

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I've created my own XML element, which is supposed to take all child LinearLayouts, create a button for each and put each inside a new ScrollView. When I go through the code step for step it appears to be working for me, except it doesnt actually give a real output. (screenshot included) I don't get any errors whatsoever.

### Screenshot:

[image].

### Code:

```
package mika.actual;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class AccordionWidget extends LinearLayout{

    AttributeSet xattrs;
    Context xcontext;

    public AccordionWidget(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        xattrs = attrs;
        xcontext = context;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        final int count = this.getChildCount();

        AttributeSet attrs = xattrs;
        Context context = xcontext;

        TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.accordion);
        String[] btns = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.buttons);
        ArrayList<LinearLayout> lls = new ArrayList <> (count);

        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
            View child = this.getChildAt(i);
            if (child instanceof LinearLayout) {
                lls.add((LinearLayout)child);
            }
        }

        for(int j = 0; j < lls.size(); j++){

            if(btns[j] == null){
                Log.e("error: ", "Please add more Button lables to the strings.xml file.");
                break;
            }

            final Button btn = new Button(context);
            final LinearLayout ll = lls.get(j);
            final ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(context);
            final int col_pressed = a.getColor(R.styleable.accordion_backgroundColorPressed, Color.BLACK);
            final int col_unpressed = a.getColor(R.styleable.accordion_backgroundColorUnpressed, Color.YELLOW); //Black and yellow, black and yellow...


            LayoutParams btnparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            LayoutParams swparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            LayoutParams llparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            btn.setText(btns[j]);
            btn.setBackgroundColor(col_pressed);
            llparams.weight = 1f;

            btn.setLayoutParams(btnparams);
            ll.setLayoutParams(llparams);
            sv.setLayoutParams(swparams);
            ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            sv.setVisibility(GONE);

            this.removeView(ll);
            sv.addView(ll);
            this.addView(sv);
            this.addView(btn);

            btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                private boolean btnstate = false;
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (btnstate) {
                        btn.setBackgroundColor(col_pressed);
                        sv.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                        btnstate = true;
                    } else {
                        btn.setBackgroundColor(col_unpressed);
                        sv.setVisibility(GONE);
                        btnstate = false;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        a.recycle();
    }
}
```

### XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mika.actual.AccordionWidget
    xmlns:accordion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    accordion:text_color="@color/text_color"
    accordion:backgroundColorPressed="@color/button_pressed"
    accordion:backgroundColorUnpressed="@color/button_not_pressed"
    android:id="@+id/swaggy"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="yolooooo yooo"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="yolooooo yooo"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="yolooooo yooo"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="yolooooo yooo"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="yolooooo yooo"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</mika.actual.AccordionWidget>
```

Comment: you have to call `super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b)` or lay out the children on your own

Comment: @Blackbelt Hey! I've got some output! Thanks. Not quite there yet though haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `match_parent` I used `wrap_content` for the scrollView and set the weight of the ScrollView to one for the result I was looking for. I also added some ArrayLists and put all the Buttons and ScrollViews inside to close all opened panels when opening another one, so only one is opened at a time.

### My finished code:

```
package mika.actual;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AccordionWidget extends LinearLayout{


    ArrayList<Button> btnViews = new ArrayList <> ();
    ArrayList<ScrollView> svViews = new ArrayList <> ();
    AttributeSet xattrs;
    Context xcontext;

    public AccordionWidget(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        xattrs = attrs;
        xcontext = context;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
        final int count = this.getChildCount();

        AttributeSet attrs = xattrs;
        Context context = xcontext;

        TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.accordion);
        String[] btns = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.button_lables);
        ArrayList<LinearLayout> lls = new ArrayList <> (count);

        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
            View child = this.getChildAt(i);
            if (child instanceof LinearLayout) {
                lls.add((LinearLayout)child);
            }
        }

        for(int j = 0; j < lls.size(); j++){

            if(btns[j] == null){
                throw new NullPointerException("Needs more Button lables in strings.xml");
            }

            final Button btn = new Button(context);
            final LinearLayout ll = lls.get(j);
            final ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(context);
            final int col_pressed = a.getColor(R.styleable.accordion_buttonColorPressed, Color.BLACK);
            final int col_unpressed = a.getColor(R.styleable.accordion_buttonColorUnpressed, Color.YELLOW); //Black and yellow, black and yellow...

            LayoutParams btnparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            LayoutParams svparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            LayoutParams llparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            btn.setText(btns[j]);
            btn.setBackgroundColor(col_unpressed);
            svparams.weight = 1f;

            btn.setLayoutParams(btnparams);
            ll.setLayoutParams(llparams);
            sv.setLayoutParams(svparams);
            ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            sv.setVisibility(GONE);

            this.removeView(ll);
            sv.addView(ll);
            this.addView(btn);
            this.addView(sv);
            btnViews.add(btn);
            svViews.add(sv);

            btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int visibility = sv.getVisibility();
                    for (int k = 0; k < btnViews.size(); k++){
                        btnViews.get(k).setBackgroundColor(col_unpressed);
                        svViews.get(k).setVisibility(GONE);
                    }

                    if (visibility == VISIBLE) {
                        btn.setBackgroundColor(col_unpressed);
                        sv.setVisibility(GONE);
                    } else {
                        btn.setBackgroundColor(col_pressed);
                        sv.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        a.recycle();
    }
}
```